# Using variable names as column names

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating an website where i am using user specified values as the column name of my table and it works fine but, when it comes to update it am unable to do it in the same process
here are my codes to create a column name from user specified value

```
mysqli_query($sql,"ALTER TABLE `cmpcheck` ADD `$emailID` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ");
```

Here are my codes to update the above column

```
 mysqli_query($sql,"UPDATE cmpcheck SET `$emailID` = `".$q."` LIMIT 1  ");
```

Any Help?

Comment: The table design where users can add columns dynamically seems poor. Are you sure you need to do that?

Comment: i thought that would be useful. as i am creating an online examination system. i thought of using it as column name and storing the answers in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong quotes for your value:

```
mysqli_query($sql,"UPDATE cmpcheck SET `$emailID` = '".$q."' LIMIT 1  ");
                                                    ^      ^
```

With a backtick (`) you are referencing to a column-name.

Besides that: make sure to properly escape both `$emailID` and `$q`

Comment: @user3225075 - if it's still not working, what __error__ are you getting?

Comment: Not getting any error. or i might be able to display one. can you tell me how to view any error coz my code not showing any error

Comment: Use `$query_result = mysqli_query(...); if (!$query_result) { die(mysqli_error($sql)); }`, to get the MySQL-error. What's the value of $q?

Answer (score 0):

Backticks go around table and column names. You should use single quotes around string values.

```
mysqli_query($sql,"UPDATE cmpcheck SET `$emailID` = '$q' LIMIT 1  ");
```

Also, there's no reason to switch from variable substitution (as you do for `$emailID`) to concatenation with `.`.

It would be even better to use a prepared statement to substitute `$q`, instead of variable substitution into the query. But you can't do that for the column name.

Answer (score -1):

You could try :

```
mysqli_query($sql,"UPDATE cmpcheck SET `".$emailID."` = '".$q."' LIMIT 1 ");
```

Also look at preparing your statements.

Comment: `cmpcheck` and the column-name `$emailID` aren't values, so don't quote them like that.

Comment: Yea, I wanted to use backticks but stackoverflow thought I was ending the code.